# Java array checksum independent of element order

Tags: java, arrays, hash, checksum

Say I have two arrays, e.g. `[B,D,C,A]` and `[B,A,D,C]`. What mechanism would generate the same checksum on both arrays (and any array containing a permutation of their elements)?

In the following example, `check_a` and `check_b` will not be equal. Putting the elements into an alphabetical order is not an option, as the objects in the array might not be Strings or anything sortable at all.

```
String[] a = {"B","D","C","A"};
String[] b = {"B","A","D","C"};

String check_a = a.hashCode();
String check_b = b.hashCode();
```

Comment: Can you please proide some code which shws us [what you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example

```
public class ArrayHash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] one = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D"};
        String[] two = new String[]{"D", "C", "B", "A"};
        System.out.println("One = " + one.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Two = " + two.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Method for one = "+hash(one));
        System.out.println("Method for two = "+hash(two));
    }

    private static int hash(Object[] array) {
        int ret = 0;
        for (Object c : array) {
            ret += (124567890 + c.hashCode()) * c.hashCode();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

it gives an output

```
One = 366712642
Two = 1829164700
Method for one = 266
Method for two = 266
```

as you can see, you have to iterate over all elements and sum (or multiply) their hashes. that will give you same result no matter in what order they are.

Comment: Thank you that answers my question. However is there a way to make the sum unique too, i.e. can I somehow ensure that two rows with different entries will not have the same checksum?

Comment: hashcodes of strings are not very unikqe and are small so sums can be equal. If you wont to avoid it, you can try make it more complex like  `ret+=(1245 + c.hashCode())*25;` this is not solution yet, but you can try it and see how it will work for you

Comment: `ret += (124567890 + c.hashCode()) * c.hashCode();` this should work better

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you have a function that get checksumm of elements. To get checksum you want you need to find operation with [Commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) there are lot of them. For example `+`, `*`, `^`